# How to load @font-face last

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have some problem with font-face that are loaded are deform my div height. Is there a solution to load it last so the div would have the correct height depending of the font loaded?

**EDIT**

Yes the height of the div is the same as the line-height. Normaly it would be vertical-aligned with a default web font like arial. But with some @font-face, that doesn't work.

Comment: Surely you want the font loaded first, so the `div` is given the correct height?

Comment: Is your `div` set to a fixed height? If you're having trouble wrapping the `div` around the content, make sure you mention that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load the font-face last, you can append the  tag, or CSS rules using jQuery after the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('<link rel="stylesheet" href="myfile.css" type="text/css" />').appendTo($('head'));

});
```